# Octave: testing functions over a Range in Lists or like with For-loops?

Tags: math, matlab, octave

I want to see the values of the function y(x) with different values of x, where y(x) < 5:

> y = abs(x)+abs(x+2)-5

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fplot(@(x) abs(x)+abs(x+2)-5, [-10 10])
hold all
fplot(@(x) 5, [-10 10])
legend({'y=abs(x)+abs(x+2)-5' 'y=5'})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a vector of values `x`, then look at the vector `y`, or plot it:

```
% Create a vector with 20 equally spaced entries in the range [-1,1].
x = linspace(-1,1,20);

% Calculate y, and see the result
y = abs(x) + abs(x + 2) - 5

% Plot.
plot(x, y);

% View the minimum and maximum.
min(y)
max(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you limit `x` to the range `[-6 4]`, it will ensure that `y` will be limited to less than or equal to 5. In MATLAB, you can then plot the function using [FPLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/fplot.html) (like [Amro suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546321/octave-testing-functions-over-a-range-in-lists-or-like-with-for-loops/1546768#1546768)) or [LINSPACE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) and [PLOT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) (like [Peter suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546321/octave-testing-functions-over-a-range-in-lists-or-like-with-for-loops/1546332#1546332)):

```
y = @(x) abs(x)+abs(x+2)-5;  % Create a function handle for y
fplot(y,[-6 4]);             % FPLOT chooses the points at which to evaluate y
% OR
x = linspace(-6,4,100);      % Create 100 equally-spaced points from -6 to 4
plot(x,y(x));                % PLOT will plot the points you give it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% create a vector x with values between 1 and 5
x = 1:0.1:5;

% create a vector y with your function
y = abs(x) + abs(x+2) - 5;

% find all elements in y that are under 5
y(find(y<5))
```